# The name Section doesn't exists in current context: ASP dot net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send the css into `RenderSection` in `_Layout.cshtml` file. That is

```
@RenderSection("mycss", required: false)
```

But when I try to send the css from a razor view (.cshtml file ) it says,

> The name Section doesn't exists in current context.

My code is given below

```
@Section mycss
{
    <style>
        h2 {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "action file"? Are you putting the code into a razor view (.cshtml file), or are you putting it into a controller (.cs file)? Note that it should go into a view.

Comment: it is in a razor view (.cshtml file )

Comment: what do you get if you enclosed it in plain css without using razor?

Comment: Please give me direct solution why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

the 's' in section needs to be lower case, and intellisense is probably complaining about that in Visual Studio:

```
@section mycss
{
    <style>
        h2 
        {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
}
```

Now that I've answered the question, I just want to add that, generally speaking, I would not advise passing css like this (although I'm sure someone is going to comment about a corner case) because it is a bad practice and would recommend that you put it in a css file.